# Rate of change in a logarithmic model

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-inference

Given the following model:

$$\ln{\left(W\right)}=\beta_0+\beta_1e+\beta_2e\ast x+\beta_3e\ast\ln{\left(P\right)}
+\beta_4\ln{\left(P\right)}\ast x+ error.$$

Setting $x = 4$, and $e =3$, a $1$% increase in $P$ will lead to a __________ % increase in $W$?

I took the derivative with respect to $P$ and got:

$$\frac{\beta_3e}{P}+ \frac{\beta_4x}{P}$$

But don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You must also take the derivative of the right hand side:
$$\frac{dW}{dP} \frac{1}{W} = \frac{\beta_3e}{P}+ \frac{\beta_4x}{P} $$
so with $\delta W$ the variation of $W$ you obtain:
$$\frac{\delta W} {W} \simeq (\beta_3 e+\beta_4 x) \frac{\delta P}{P}$$

---

Note that you can obtain directly the result noticing that:
$$d \ln(W) =\frac{dW}{W}, d \ln(P) =\frac{dP}{P}$$